# Описание generic-типа с помощью объектов классов

Tags: java

Мне нужно описать некий абстрактный тип в виде класса, который сам по себе будет дженериком этого абстрактного типа (для удобств сериализации и десериализации):

```
public class TypeSpec<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final List<TypeSpec<?>> parameters;

    ...
}

List<TypeSpec<?>> parameters = Arrays.asList(new TypeSpec<>(B.class), new TypeSpec<>(C.class);
TypeSpec<A<B, C>> specification = new TypeSpec<>(A.class, parameters);
```

Проблема в том, что джава оправданно защищается и не любит такие штуки: я не могу первым параметром передать `Class<A<B, C>>`, потому что его не существует (есть только `A.class` типа `Class<A>`), а иначе ограничению типа неоткуда взяться. Как правильно разрешать такие ситуации?

Comment: типа как `TypeToken` в [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)?

Comment: @zRrr да, только времени на возню с абстрактными классами и выдергиваниями вкомпиленных типов нет. В принципе, там практически автоматом будет использоваться Jackson с его JavaTypeFactory, но не хотелось бы использовать его классы.